# ember.js: can I only render in route?

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

I need some "conceptual" advice for ember.js.

I think I understand how things work for straight forward cases when the URL changes (manually or with `transitionTo`). The route is responsible for loading the corresponding model and render a template into the parent's outlet.

**What I don't understand is**: there are some occasions where you want to change the state of the application but you do not want to (or can't) change the URL.

Let's say I have a template with two outlets:

```
<div id='dashboard'>
  <div id='top'>{{outlet top}}</div>
  <div id='bottom'>{{outlet bottom}}</div>
</div>
```

`top` and `bottom` part of the dashboard are independent of each other. Initially the application probably transitions to a `/dashboard` route which renders the initial state of `top` and `bottom` into the outlets. But what happens then? If I want to change the content of the `top` outlet, where do I render and insert that content (since there is no route involved)? Can I render in a controller? Do I have to set up a custom view container and how and where would that be rendered?

Any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure if this is the best way to go about it, but I was playing around and got it working like this:

[**Full Source**](http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/jMYQn/) | [**Run**](http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/jMYQn/show/#/dashboard)

**JavaScript**:

```
App.DashboardView = Em.View.extend({
    starActive: true,
    userActive: false,
    heartActive: false,
    resetDisplay: function() {
        this.set('starActive', false);
        this.set('userActive', false);
        this.set('heartActive', false);
    },
    star: function() { 
        console.log('star'); 
        this.resetDisplay();
        this.set('starActive', true);
    },
    user: function() {
        console.log('user'); 
        this.resetDisplay();
        this.set('userActive', true);
    },
    heart: function() {
        console.log('heart'); 
        this.resetDisplay();
        this.set('heartActive', true);
    }
});
```

**Handlebars**:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="_navDashboard">
    <ul class="nav-list">
        <li class="nav-header">Actions</li>
        <li>
            <a {{action star target="view"}}><i class="icon-star"></i> One</a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a {{action user target="view"}}><i class="icon-user"></i> Two</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a {{action heart target="view"}}><i class="icon-heart"></i> Three</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="dashboard/user">
    <h3>User</h3>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="dashboard/star">
    <h3>Star</h3>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="dashboard/heart">
    <h3>Heart</h3>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="dashboard">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <h2>Dashboard</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span3">
            <div class="well sidebar-nav">
              {{partial navDashboard}}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="span7">
            {{#if view.starActive}}
                {{render "dashboard/star"}}
            {{/if}}
            {{#if view.userActive}}
                {{render "dashboard/user"}}
            {{/if}}
            {{#if view.heartActive}}
                {{render "dashboard/heart"}}
            {{/if}}
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

I'm not sure about this solution because it makes the developer responsible for managing when to render or not a certain template or view; depending on the complexity it would be easier to make a mistake and leave more than one view display at the time, or even display the wrong view, but that's what I got at the moment.

Comment: I think that's probably the way to go. My use case is a bit more complex, but I will try to go that path...

Comment: btw: why are you setting the target of the action to the view? Wouldn't it be more natural to handle the events in the controller?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. It really depends. I found myself handling events in the routes a lot lately, so my controllers have actions that pretty much do `this.get('target').send('eventName', this.get('content'));` only and I handle it in the route. Like I said, depends on what you're doing or trying to do. Just make sure you're consistent on either approach.